# Autowire of prototype bean into prototype bean?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working with some existing code and it is doing things I haven't seen before.  I've dealt with autowiring prototype beans into singletons using method injection or getting the bean from the context using getBean().  What I am seeing in this code I am working on is a bean that is a prototype and retrieved using getBean(), and it has autowired dependencies.  Most of these are singleton beans, which makes sense.  But there is an autowire of another prototype bean, and from what I see, it does seem like it is getting a new bean.  My question is when you autowire a prototype into a prototype, will that give you a new instance?  Since the autowire request is not at startup but rather when this bean is created, does it go and create a new instance?  This goes against what I thought about autowire and prototype beans and I wanted to hear an answer from out in the wild.  Thanks for any insight.  I'm trying to minimize my refactoring of this code as it is a bit spaghetti-ish.

example:

```
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyPrototypeClass  {

    @Autowired
    private ReallyGoodSingletonService svc;

    @Autowired
    private APrototypeBean bean;

    public void doSomething() {
        bean.doAThing();
    }
}

@Scope("prototype)
public class APrototypeBean {
   private int stuffgoeshere;

   public void doAThing() {
   }
}
```

So when doSomething() in MyPrototypeClass is called, is that "bean" a singleton or a new one for each instance of MyPrototypeClass?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your example, the `APrototypeBean` bean will be set to a brand new bean which will live through until the instance of `MyPrototypeClass` that you created is destroyed.

If you create a second instance of `MyPrototypeClass` then that second instance will receive its own `APrototypeBean`. With your current configuration, every time you call `doSomething()`, the method will be invoked on an instance of `APrototypeBean` that is unique for that `MyPrototypeClass` object.

Comment: Nice explanation @Mark Laren

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of `@Autowired` or autowiring in general is flawed. Autowiring occurs when an instance of the bean is created and not at startup.

If you would have a singleton bean that is lazy and that bean isn't directly used nothing would happen as soon as you would retrieve the bean using for instance `getBean` on the application context an instance would be created, dependencies get wired, `BeanPostProcessors` get applied etc.

This is the same for each and every type of bean it will be processed as soon as it is created not before that.

Now to answer your question a prototype bean is a prototype bean so yes you will receive fresh instances with each call to `getBean`.

Comment: thanks - so I understand that the retrieval of a bean using getBean gives you a new instance. That is by definition for the prototype.  But inside that bean, if there is an autowire of a prototype-scope bean, does that also create a new instance of that bean? That's what I haven't seen before.

Comment: Why shouldn't it. As I stated when the bean is created it gets its dependencies injected, those dependencies are also retrieved using `getBean` so the same applies again. I thought that was already clear in my answer. The moment of creation is also the moment of injection, proxy creation etc. and for which scope the application context doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more explanation to @Mark Laren's answer.

As explained in [Spring 4.1.6 docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection)

> In most application scenarios, most beans in the container are
>   singletons. When a singleton bean needs to collaborate with another
>   singleton bean, or a non-singleton bean needs to collaborate with
>   another non-singleton bean, you typically handle the dependency by
>   defining one bean as a property of the other. A problem arises when
>   the bean lifecycles are different. Suppose singleton bean A needs to
>   use non-singleton (prototype) bean B, perhaps on each method
>   invocation on A. The container only creates the singleton bean A once,
>   and thus only gets one opportunity to set the properties. The
>   container cannot provide bean A with a new instance of bean B every
>   time one is needed.

Below approach **will solve** this problem, but this is **not** desirable because this code **couples business code with Spring framework** and **violating** IOC pattern. The following is an example of this approach:

```
// a class that uses a stateful Command-style class to perform some processing
package fiona.apple;

// Spring-API imports
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class CommandManager implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Object process(Map commandState) {
        // grab a new instance of the appropriate Command
        Command command = createCommand();
        // set the state on the (hopefully brand new) Command instance
        command.setState(commandState);
        return command.execute();
    }

    protected Command createCommand() {
        // notice the Spring API dependency!
        return this.applicationContext.getBean("command", Command.class);
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(
            ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

So, there are 2 desirable ways to solve this problem.

**1. Using Spring's method injection**

- As name suggests, Spring will **implement & inject our abstract method** by using @Lookup annotation from **Spring 4** or  tag if you use xml version. Refer [this DZone article](https://dzone.com/articles/method-injection-spring).

By using @Lookup.

> from Java Doc...
>
> > An annotation that indicates 'lookup' methods, to be overridden by the
> >     container to redirect them back to the BeanFactory for a getBean call.
> >     This is essentially an annotation-based version of the XML
> >     lookup-method attribute, resulting in the same runtime arrangement.
>
> Since:
>   4.1

```
@Component
public class MyClass1 {
  doSomething() {
    myClass2();
  }

  //I want this method to return MyClass2 prototype
  @Lookup
  public MyClass2 myClass2(){
    return null; // No need to declare this method as "abstract" method as
                 //we were doing with earlier versions of Spring & <lookup-method> xml version. 
                 //Spring will treat this method as abstract method and spring itself will provide implementation for this method dynamically.
  }
}
```

The above example will create new myClass2 instance each time.

**2. Using Provider from Java EE (Dependency Injection for Java (JSR 330)).**

```
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Component
    public static class SomeRequest {}

    @Service
    public static class SomeService {

        @Autowired
        javax.inject.Provider<SomeRequest> someRequestProvider;

        SomeRequest doSomething() {
            return someRequestProvider.get();
        }
    }
```

The above example will create new SomeRequest instance each time.