# Get New Instance Of Prototype Scoped Spring Component Using JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I want to have a Spring component with prototype scope instantiated as needed at runtime, using pure Java implementation (Spring JavaConfig annotations).
Say i have a bean as follows:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")   
public class MyTask {

    @Autowired
    Field myField;

    runTask() {...}
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
MyTask task = //instantiate new task
task.runTask();
```

I can always use:

```
ApplicationContext.getBean(MyTask.class)
```

But that would completely contradict the notion of inversion of control.
Can this be done with JavaConfig pure Java implementation (i.e. no use of xml files)?

**UPDATE:**

To be more specific, I'm looking for a way that will be similar to the xml based solution of lookup-method factory that is explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495353/get-new-instance-of-a-spring-bean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope 'prototype' means that each time you call `beanFactory.getBean()`, you get a fresh instance. And when you inject a dependency (for instance, via @Autowired), Spring (internally) calls that `getBean()` only once per injection point.

To call it multiple times, you need a `BeanFactory`, or just call that `@Bean`-annotated method in your configuration.

An interesting use case of prototype scope with @Configuration is described here: [Spring Java Config: how do you create a prototype-scoped @Bean with runtime arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155832/spring-java-config-how-do-you-create-a-prototype-scoped-bean-with-runtime-argu?rq=1)

### Update

You could implement what you described without the prototype scope.

```
@Component
public class MyTaskFactoryImpl implements MyTaskFactory {
    @Autowired
    Field myField;

    @Override
    public MyTask newTask() {
        return new MyTask(myField);
    }
}
```

And in `MyTask`:

```
public class MyTask {

    final Field myField;

    public MyTask(Field myField) {
        this.myField = myField;
    }

    public void runTask() {...}
}
```

Then inject `MyTaskFactory taskFactory` and use it:

```
MyTask task = taskFactory.newTask();
task.runTask()
```

Comment: Thanks @rpuch this however make use of Beanfactory.getBean(..) which I prefer not to use. Is this the only way to instantiate a Bean at runtime?

Comment: @zuckermanori no such a way comes to my mind. But I've updated the answer with an example of how this can be done without using prototype scope (no `BeanFactory` either).

Comment: Thank you @rpuch this is what I had in mind before, still wanted to look for a way to do that. I'll upvote for the creativity, and wait for other answers to come.